# Select personalizado com script conflitante

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, woocommerce

Então, eu tenho um script para alterar o select padrão das variações do WooCommerce, até aí tudo bem, o problema é quando uma variação está fora de estoque, o select personalizado deveria ter as mesmas opções que o select padrão.

"Select" personalizado acima, padrão abaixo. Branco e P estão fora de estoque.

[image: "Select" personalizado acima, padrão abaixo. Branco e P estão fora de estoque.]

Descobri que o script [Variations JS do WooCommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js) remove as opções fora de estoque programaticamente, mas como o meu script é executado após o script do WooCommerce eu pensei que deveria funcionar. Eu até consegui fazer funcionar adicionando um setTimeout de 2000ms, mas é muito longo e na verdade quebra outras funções que eu tenho. Ficarei grato se alguém souber como resolver isso.

```js
$('.variations select').each(function(){
    var select = $(this);
    var div = $('<div class="grupo-atributos">');
    var ul = $('<ul>');
    select.parent('.value').siblings('.label').find('label').each(function(){
      var label = $(this).text();
      div.append('<span>'+label+'</span>');
    });

    $('#custom-select-produto-variavel').append(div);
    div.append(ul);

    select.find('option').each(function(){
      var titulo = $(this).text();
      var data_value = $(this).val();
      ul.append('<li data-value='+data_value+'>'+titulo+'</li>');
    
    select.change(function(){
    select.find('option:selected').each(function(){
      var opcao_selected = $(this);
      select.find('option:not(:selected)').each(function(){
        var opcao_not_selected = $(this);
        $('#custom-select-produto-variavel li').each(function(){
          var opcao_custom = $(this);
          if(opcao_custom.attr('data-value')==opcao_selected.val())
              opcao_custom.addClass('atributo-selected');
          if(opcao_custom.attr('data-value')==opcao_not_selected.val())
              opcao_custom.removeClass('atributo-selected');
        });
      });
    });
    }).change();

    });
  });

  $('#custom-select-produto-variavel div ul li:contains("Escolha uma opção")').remove();

  $('#custom-select-produto-variavel ul li').click(function() {
    var novoVal = $(this).data('value');
    $('.variations select:has([value='+novoVal+'])').val(novoVal);
    $('.variations select').trigger('change');
  });
```

```html
<div id="custom-select-produto-variavel"></div>
```

Comment: Tenta colocando o código dentro de um `$(window).on("load", function(){ CÓDIGO AQUI });`

Comment: Já havia tentado, não funciona, é como se o Variations JS continuasse rodando após a página carregar, muito estranho.

Comment: Dá pra fazer umas gambi com setInterval, mas acho que não vale a pena.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que o select padrão tem um atraso de 100 ms para iniciar, portanto, para fazer meu script funcionar corretamente, eu precisei adicionar essas linhas.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
 // Meu script
}, 150);
});
```